# Cannot set state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the result from the session and set its state in my react component.
But every time I am getting the memory leak problem due to which I am unable to set my session status to true.

My useEffect code looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 let mounted = true;
  getSession()
    .then(session => {
      console.log('session: ', session);
      if (mounted) {
      setStatus(true);
     }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('inside error or no session found');
      console.log(e);
    });

 return () => {
   mounted = false;
 };
}, [status, getSession]);
```

I tried these methods to solve my problem:  **Boolean Flag to Control the useEffect** and **AbortController to clean the useEffect**, but both of them did not work.

can you please suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: If you remove the cleanup, does the error exist?

Comment: Have you tried enwrapping getSession in a `useCallback` hook?

Comment: It may be more useful to dig into why the component is unmounting before you expect it to.

Comment: @TusharShahi yes, even after removing the cleanup the error exists.

Comment: @AreebKhan Now I tried useCallback hook also, but nothing works :(

Answer (score 1):

The name of your `mounted` variable suggests you're expecting that effect callback to only fire on first mount, and the cleanup to only fire on dismount, but your dependency array ensures that the cleanup and effect callback happen **every time** `status` or `getSession` changes.

You don't use `status` in the callback, so you should remove that to avoid triggering the effect when setting it `true`. If `getSession` is stable (doesn't change) across the life of the component, you can remove that as well. Then, with an empty dependency array, your callback will only get called on mount, and your cleanup will only get called on dismount.

---

Just a side note: If you can modify `getSession` to accept an `AbortSignal` you can use to tell it to cancel its operation proactively, in general that's preferable. For instance, if you were using `fetch` (perhaps `getSession` does under the covers?), you could do that because `fetch` accepts an `AbortSignal`. Details: [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController), [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal)

Comment: I removed the status and getSession from the callback but still, the problem is there.

Comment: @Ragu - What is the "memory leak" you're seeing?

Comment: the problem is, it has given the memory leak error the first time. After that, it is not giving errors but not even updating the state.

Comment: @Ragu - "it has given the memory leak error the first time" - *what* has given? The first time you do what? Use the component, but not afterward? Run the project, but not the second time?

Comment: I have a login button, after clicking it, it redirects to the dashboard where I check the session and set the status according to it. 
The first time after I load the project, I click on login then it has given this error: ``Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`` After that it has not given any error and do not even set the value.

Comment: @Ragu - The code you've shown won't cause that warning (unless `getSession` itself does some state change that you haven't mentioned), it must be in other code in the project. You're correctly ensuring that you don't set state on this component when it's been unmounted (assuming you've made the change you said you'd made so you now have an empty dependency array).

Comment: `const getSession = async () => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
      if (user) {
        user.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            reject();
          } else {
            resolve(session);
          }
        });
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  };`
 This is the getSession function that I am using in my contextProvider.
Does this looks fine?

Comment: @Ragu - What you need to do is find where you're setting state on an unmounted component. I assume `getSession` and the things it calls don't set state on components. The component code you've shown **also** doesn't set state on an unmounted component. So you have to go looking for the **component** code that does.